# Adding action handler using data-ember-action in Ember.js

Tags: jquery, ember.js, datatables

I noticed that when I have a {{action}} in Ember, it is rendered as data-ember-action="SomeNumber". I tried using data-ember-action directly in the HTML and that also works. Now I want to find out what id is assigned to a particular action handler and can I assign an Id to the action handler myself? Actually I am using jquery datatables plugin to display some data. This data has to be displayed as links and on clicking the links certain action handler must be invoked. If I try to use {{action}} in the code it renders as {{action}} in html. I want to call an action handler called open with parameter data.name as shown in the code below

```
App.SearchView = Em.View.extend({
data: function(){
},
tagName:'table',
didInsertElement: function(){  
var mod=this.get('controller').get('model');
var self=this;
 this.$().dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "aaData":mod,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "name" }
    ],
    "aoColumnDefs": [ 
      {
        "fnRender": function ( oObj ) { 
          var data=oObj.aData;
          return '<br/><a {{action open data.name}}>' + data.name " </a>";           
        },
        "aTargets": [0]
      }
]
} );
```

}
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem on a different stackoverflow post. 
[YUI with emberjs Datatable with ember dynamic link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756881/yui-with-emberjs-datatable-with-ember-dynamic-link?noredirect=1#comment34419534_21756881)

Answer (score 0):

Generally in cases where it is required to access ember entities from the DOM using pure js, for example when required to handle an `onclick` js event and delegate it to `ember` entities, one way i have found helpful is to have a generic function returning an  `ember view` passing a DOM element and handle the action.Something like,

```
function getView($el){
  return Ember.View.views[$el.closest(".ember-view").attr("id")];
}
```

....

```
return '<br/><a href=# onclick="getView($(this)).get(\'controller\').send(\'open\','+ data.name+')">'+data.name+'</a>';
```

Basically it is based on what you have posted .